# Find the line numbers of exception lines in log file

Tags: text-processing

I am writing a shell script program to extract some exceptions from a log file and do some processing. 
Currently I am using the below command in my script to capture the line nos in the log file that has an exception. The exception lines will contains `ERROR` keyord just after date and timestamp

```
lineNos=($(grep -n ERROR $file | grep Exception | cut -d':' -f1 | tail -3))
```

While testing the current script, I noticed that some log entries contains ERROR and Exceptions in the same row but which is not actually the kind of ERROR that I am looking for(Example line 5) 
I would like to modify my script in such a way that it will return only the line no 3 in the below example log.

```
2016-10-21 15:25:37,231 INFO Processinng current row  
2016-10-21 15:25:37,231 INFO com.test.main com.test.controller.CrashException: 
2016-10-21 15:25:37,231 ERROR com.test.main com.test.controller.CrashException: 
2016-10-21 15:25:37,231 DEBUG com.test.main com.test.controller.CrashException: 
2016-10-21 15:25:37,231 DEBUG Processing row with ERROR and Exception 
2016-10-21 15:25:37,231 DEBUG processed row 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the lines with the words `ERROR` and `Exception`, try:

```
grep -E "ERROR.*Exception" $file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `awk` in place of `grep`, you can not only print just the line numbers (more precisely, *record numbers*) directly, but also test specific whitespace-delimited fields individually e.g.

```
awk '$3 == "ERROR" && /Exception/ {print NR}' logfile
```

or (even more specifically - limiting the match of `Exception` to the final field)

```
awk '$3 == "ERROR" && $NF ~ /Exception/ {print NR}' logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat thelogfile.log | nl -ba | grep "ERROR"
```

This will pipe the file to nl to number lines, then filter with grep for error lines. if you just want the error line numbers, add awk '{print $1}'. Also cat can line numbers with the -n flag, but i prefer nl.

example for an array variable of line numbers with errors;

```
linenos=($(cat -n thelogfile.log | grep "ERROR" | awk '{print $1}' | tr "\n" " " | sed 's/$/\n/'))
```

Edit:

ps the grep can be;

```
grep ",[0-9]* ERROR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using more specific regex:

```
grep '^[0-9, :-]\+ERROR' "$file"
```